# Static variables in an Abstract Class java

Tags: java, class, static

If I have an abstract class that has variables of the form

```
protected static final int blah;
protected static final int blah2;
```

And i have two classes that extend this abstract class, and set these variables to "static final int" values from a constants file in their constructors, will they clobber eachother's values? If I want to do such a thing, what would you recommend I do?

So, for example, if i have

impl1 class:

```
public impl1 extends absClass{
    public impl1(){
        this.blah = CONSTANTS.impl1_blah;
        this.blah2 = CONSTANTS.impl1_blah2;
    }
}
```

impl2 class:

```
public impl2 extends absClass{
    public impl2(){
        this.blah = CONSTANTS.impl2_blah;
        this.blah2 = CONSTANTS.impl2_blah2;
    }
}
```

Is this allowed? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
this.blah = CONSTANTS.impl2_blah;
this.blah2 = CONSTANTS.impl2_blah;
```

> this allowed?

This *isn't* allowed, since your `blah` variables are declared as `final`. You must initialize them during class initialization, either in their declaration or in a static initializer block.

Furthermore, these variables are `static`, and so accessing them using `this` won't work: the variables belong to the *class* and not an *instance*.

> If not, what should I do?

Use non-final variables in the superclass, or use specific constants in the subclasses.

Comment: Sorry, i made an edit, i added '2's' at the end of them, is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

if classes extending that abstract class are supposed to give their own values for those variables then you should consider a couple of protected abstract methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables can't be overridden. Those will be associated with the classes where you have defined them.

Comment: So basically, impl2's blah variable will not equal impl1's blah variable right? And why can't I use the this keyword?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I mis-understood this.blah in your question, if this.blah is impl1 variable, then no issues.

Comment: Correction: `final` variables can't be overwritten. You can overwrite `static` variables just fine, but that changes them for anything accessing them anywhere else in this process.

Comment: @Supuhstar: Are you sure? Check my sample below. As per your theory, when I assign 50 to temp in Superclass and print it from MySubClass it should give me 50, but printing 30.

Comment: public abstract class MySuperClass {
    
    public static int temp = 10;
}

public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass{
    public static int temp = 30;
}
public class MyTestClasss {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MySuperClass.temp  =50;
        
        System.out.println(MySubClass.temp);
    }
}

Comment: @Supuhstar: And better read this to understand difference between overriding and hiding. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: @Nambari See, you create two variables, there. You've explicitly hidden `MySuperClass`'s `temp`, making it distinct from the new `MySubClass` `temp`. My below example will print 50.

Comment: `public abstract class MySuperClass { public static int temp = 10; } public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass { static { temp = 30; } } public class MyTestClasss { public static void main(String[] args) { MySuperClass.temp =50; System.out.println(MySubClass.temp); } } `

Answer (score 0):

`static final` variables must be initialized when the class that declares them is initialized. This is before any instances of the class (or any subclass) are created. Your code won't compile without some sort of initialization for `blah` and `blah2`—either an initialization expression:

```
protected static final int blah = 42;
protected static final int blah2 = 1;
```

or in a static initializer block:

```
protected static final int blah;
protected static final int blah2;
static {
    blah = 42;
    blah2 = 1;
}
```

In either case, subclasses have no say in what `blah` and `blah2` get assigned.

It seems from your example code that you want constants that can vary on a per-instance basis. It doesn't make sense for them to be static. You can do something like this:

```
public AbsClass {
    protected final int blah;
    protected final int blah2;
    protected AbsClass(int blah, int blah2) {
        this.blah = blah;
        this.blah2 = blah2;
    }
    . . .
}

public class Impl1 extends AbsClass {
    public Impl1() {
        super(CONSTANTS.impl1_blah, CONSTANTS.impl1_blah2);
    }
}

public class Impl2 extends AbsClass {
    public Impl1() {
        super(CONSTANTS.impl2_blah, CONSTANTS.impl2_blah2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism in Java don't work with attributes. Use some protected abstract getMethods() instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is final+static which means nothing to do with OOP, If you make them not static then It makes sense to talk about OOP on it. If you do not do them as private and access them using getters/setters then you are breaking encapsulation.

And you are making it final, means it can be initialized only once. You will get exception when you try to change the value of final attr.